# Error formatting a DateTime object with joda time's JSP tag

Tags: java, jsp-tags, jodatime

I have a problem when passing a DateTime object to my JSP, the joda:format tag takes the attribute value as a String.

Here is my JSP:

```
<joda:format value="${next.date}" style="FF" />
```

next is an object with the following code:

```
/**
 * @return the date
 */
public DateTime getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

And here is my Exception:

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: value
>   attribute of format tag must be a
>   ReadableInstant or   ReadablePartial,
>   was: java.lang.String

I've even tried doing this directly from the jsp to no avail:

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("now", new org.joda.time.DateTime()); %>
<joda:format value="${now}" style="FF" />
```

Don't understand why I get this exception, can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

This exception means that "${...}" is parsed like normal String, so check if your application using EL expressions. [From documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/jsptags/userguide.html):

> you should ensure that your
>   application is using servlet
>   specification 2.4. This is usually
>   controlled by the web.xml file. If you
>   do not do this then EL expressions
>   will not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help, added this lines into web.xml file and works

Comment: This lines: <web-app version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd">